# How to save custom object in sqlite using objective c

Tags: ios, sqlite

I am saving my object "message" which belongs to QBChatMessage class having the following properties

```
 ID: 1408191795.427892 
 senderID: 0 
 recipientID: 0 
 datetime: 2014-08-16 12:23:15 +0000 
 text: (null) 
 customParameters: (null) 
 attachments: (null)
 delayed: 0 
 senderNick: (null)
```

i am saving it in database with this piece of code

```
NSData *dataFromArray = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:message];

[[DBManager sharedDatabase]saveUserChatHistory:dataFromArray :self.dialog.ID];
```

in my function (saveUSerChatHistory) I save the data using sqlite3_bind_blob function

and getting back from sqlite using the following code

```
QBChatMessage *message=[[QBChatMessage alloc]init];

message = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:myData];
```

and while doing that I and getting the following error

```
-[NSKeyedUnarchiver initForReadingWithData:]: incomprehensible archive (0x35, 0x33, 0x65, 0x66, 0x31, 0x30, 0x30, 0x64).
```

I am neither using core data nor FMDB, Please help me to know how can I save my object in sqlite.